# SSIS How to get part of a string (name value tokens in a variable)

Tags: ssis

I have three variables:

1. "v_LocationsByCode" with value of below.

> Code1="location1";Code2="location2";

2. "v_Code" with value of either Code1 or Code2 (or Code3 if v_LocationsByCode has it, etc)
3. "v_Location" this is a variable with expression, and its value will be used depending on value of "v_Code"

So:

```
If v_Code is "Code1" then v_Location should be "location1"
Else If v_Code is "Code2" then v_Location should be "location2"
Else If ...
Else ""
```

Can you help me with the expression (without hardcoding)?
I was able to do this in sql using a bunch of substring(), charindex() and len(), however SSIS-expression does not have charindex(). It has findstring() but it's missing "starting location".

Comment: What are "v_LocationsByCode","v_Code", "v_Location"  columns ? and which ssis component are using to get your expected output?

Comment: Hi, they are string variables. No component, just variable.

Comment: Where are you using that SSIS-expression ?

Comment: Using them in SSIS variables. Sorry I don't understand why you asked :). SSIS has variables and they can be expression.

Comment: I mean in which scope ?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression in `v_Location` should be like below :

```
@[User::v_Code]=="location1"? "location1" : "location2"
```

[image]